# Set the scale in ggplot to be 1:1 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to set the x and y axis in the following plot to have the same scale distance (i.e. 0.1 on the x axis is the same length as 0.1 on the y axis). Any advice? Thanks.

```
df <-data.frame(x = c(0,0.2,0.5), y = c(0.6,0.7,0.9))

p <-ggplot(df, aes(x, y, ymin=0, ymax=1, xmin=0, xmax=1))

p <- p + geom_point(alpha=2/10, shape=21, fill="blue", colour="black", size=5)

grid.arrange(p, p,ncol=1)

p
```

[image]

Comment: Andy gives an idea.  You can also just take care of this by roughly doubling our height in your plotting device as in: `png("name", width = 400, height = 800)`

Comment: You just do par(asp=1) and its all set... oh no, because this isn't base graphics, the way its been done for 25 years, this is ggplot and EVERYTHING YOU EVER LEARNT IS WRONG!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `coord_equal()`

```
df <-data.frame(x = c(0,0.2,0.5), y = c(0.6,0.7,0.9))
p <-ggplot(df, aes(x, y, ymin=0, ymax=1, xmin=0, xmax=1))
p <- p + geom_point(alpha=2/10, shape=21, fill="blue", colour="black", size=5)

p + coord_equal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your width and height of your graphic device with height = 2*width

```
library('ggplot2')
library('gridExtra')
df <-data.frame(x = c(0,0.2,0.5), y = c(0.6,0.7,0.9))

p <-ggplot(df, aes(x, y, ymin=0, ymax=1, xmin=0, xmax=1))

p <- p + geom_point(alpha=2/10, shape=21, fill="blue", colour="black", size=5)

w <- 550
png("test.png", width=w, height=2*w, units="px")

grid.arrange(p, p,ncol=1)

dev.off()
```

[image: test.png]